# How can I send message to phone by using diafaan sms gateway with php

Tags: php

I want to send message from web to phone by using diafaan sms gateway .But I cann't send message by using their diafaan server api.The error is "no recipient phone".If I substitute to="my phone number",it correctly sent.How can I do that?

```
 $diafaan_user = "admin";
  $diafaan_password = "";
  $diafaan_url="http://localhost:9710/http/send-message?username=admin&password=&to=%2B44xxxxxxxx&message-type=sms.automatic&message=Message+Text";  
   function diafaanSend($phone_no, $activate_code, $debug=false){
      global $diafaan_user,$diafaan_password,$diafaan_url;

      $url.= 'username='.$diafaan_user;
      $url.= '&password='.$diafaan_password;
      $url.= '&action=sendmessage';
      $url.= '&messagetype=sms.automatic';
      $url.= '&recipient='.urlencode($phone_no);
      $url.= '&message='.urlencode($activate_code);

      $urltouse =$diafaan_url.$url;
      if ($debug) { echo "Request: <br>$urltouse<br><br>"; }
      echo $urltouse;

   }
    /*GET data from sendsms.html*/
   $phone_no;
   $activate_code;  
  diafaanSend($phone_no, $activate_code);
   /*Insert into database*/
   if ($phone_no!='') {

      $sql = "INSERT INTO messageout (receiver,activate_code,status) ".
              "VALUES ('$phone_no','$activate_code','send')";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error()); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By your code you only define phone_no - `$phone_no;` 
You must get it from $_GET params - `$phone_no = $_GET['phone_no'];`, for example.